C convert 2 sequential uint8_t to one uint16_t
My goal is to convert an array that has two uint8_t to one unint16_t.
int main() {
    uint8_t bytes[] = {0, 126};
    uint8_t *pointer = bytes;
    printf("Hex: %x", (*(uint16_t*)pointer));
}

output
Hex: 7e00                                                                                                                 

Why is output 7e00 ?
shouldn't the bytes array look like this in memory 0x00 0x7e  ?
and when telling C to cast pointer to uint16_t* and print what it's pointing to I expect it to print 007e.
But that wasn't the case!

The way a uint16_t is layed out in memory depends on the Endianness of your system.

*(uint16_t*)pointer is undefined behavior so anything can happen.

Apart from that, check out What is CPU endianness?

I tested on android with JNI and returned this value to java which uses big endian and I printed the value returned in java and it was 32256 which is 7e00

@Ammar Programming languages don't use endianess, CPUs do.

My goal is to convert an array that has two uint8_t to one unint16_t

uint16_t value = bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1];

Here you find a good explanation of byte order and how to modify integers for your system

@Lundin "Programming languages don't use endianess, CPUs do." interesting that C2X has "7.18.2 Endian" in the library 7.18 Bit and byte utilities <stdbit.h>.  Perhaps C, or at least its standard library, is becoming more endian aware?

@chux It is simply functions used to fetch endianness. The C language has no say in the matter of which endianness that is used on the target.

And spending one minute to write down a simple macro to detect endianness is apparently mission impossible for some programmers, so the C standard has to spoon feed it to them. #define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN() (*(uint8_t*)&(uint16_t){0xAABB} == 0xBB)

Or another one-minute-of-your-time version: #define IS_LITTLE_ENDIAN() ( (union { uint8_t u8[2]; uint16_t u16; }){.u16=0xAABB}.u8[0] == 0xBB )


shouldn't the bytes array look like this in memory 0x00 0x7e ?

The way the order of bytes in memory are interpreted as a uint16_t depends on the Endianness of your system.
Also *(uint16_t*)pointer) invokes undefined-behavior since the pointer does not hold an address of a valid uint16_t. This means the standard gives no guarantee for the output of the program.

My goal is to convert an array that has two uint8_t to one unint16_t

As commented above you can use a combination of bit shifts and bit-wise ORs to achieve that:
uint16_t value = (uint16_t)bytes[0] << 8 | (uint16_t)bytes[1];

Note that as @Lundin commented below, the cast of the first byte to uint16_t is required for conforming with systems where int is 16 bit (although it's not very common). The cast of the second byte is not strictly required, but here to avoid an implicit conversion.
Live demo

You don't have to invert the bytes on different systems, your code will always produce the same result. What is important is if the uint8_t array represents an little or big endian u16. The C language itself has no notion of endianess

@Fredrik oops, my mistake. fixed.

How about converting an array of 8 sequential bytes to one uint64_t I need that for websockets too.

You can do something similar by combining shifts and bitwise ORs.

@Ammar you shift all 8 bytes a different amount, also you have to know if the array represents an uint64_t in little or big endian.

@Fredrik  I tried this approach and it gave this warning.
shift count >= width of type. and the result was wrong it was 0xffffffffffffffff

@Ammar try casting the first byte to uint64_t.

@Ammar you are not allowed to shift the same or more than the width of the type. If you are shifting uint8_t you have to cast them to uint64_t first. Also you have to know if the array represent little or big endian because it affects which bytes you shift where.

Casting worked. Thanks.

@Ammar great !  If you still have problems with the uint64_t conversion please post a new question with all the details and a [mre].

bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1] could easily invoke undefined behavior on a system with 16 bit int. Best practices involve casting the left operand of shift to a large unsigned integer type before shifting.

@Lundin do you mean something like: uint16_t value = (uint16_t)(((uint32_t)bytes[0]) << 8 | bytes[1]); ?

@wohlstad Since the code is only going to invoke UB on systems with 16 bit int, it would be sufficient to just do (uint16_t)bytes[0] << 8 | (uint16_t)bytes[1]. Where the right-most cast isn't necessary functionality-wise, but gets rid of the implicit conversion.

@Lundin got it, thanks - updated my answer.

As the other colleagues already mentioned, it depends on the endianness of the targeted systems.
A work-around if I understood what you are trying to do is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define NUMBER_OF_BYTES     4

// the index of half word you are trying to read
uint16_t get_halfword(uint8_t* bytes, uint32_t index);
uint16_t get_halfword(uint8_t* bytes, uint32_t index)
{
    return (uint16_t)bytes[(index*2)] << 8 | (uint16_t)bytes[(index*2)+1];
}

int main() {
    uint8_t bytes[NUMBER_OF_BYTES] = {0, 126, 5, 12};
    printf("Hex: %04x\n", get_halfword(bytes,0));
    printf("Hex: %04x\n", get_halfword(bytes,1));
}

However, make sure you guard against the out-of-bound scenarios.

There are three main concepts that you need to take care when you play around with pointers

Padding (does not apply in your case)
Little Endian verses Big Endian
Signed verses Unsigned datatypes (where is the sign bit is stored, 2's complement form)

I do not see any value or business need to do such typecast and it will always involve a lot of dependency on compilers and CPU architecture.
Not to mention that signed vs unsigned
Try to write clean and maintabnle code instead

I actually need to do that when implementing websocket. I need to read from socket byte by byte and the payload length of a websocket frame can be 7 bits, 16 bits or 64 bits.

Although it is not a direct answer to your question, the code below contains a more C Standards compatible version of what you want to do (as @Lundin pointed in comment).
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef union {
    uint16_t iVarInt;
    uint8_t aVarArray[2];
} tUni;
// iVarInt (2 bytes) and aVarArray[2] (1 + 1 = 2 bytes)
// both point to the same memory location.

int main() {
    uint8_t bytes[] = {0, 126};
    uint8_t *pointer = bytes;
    tUni varComposite;
    tUni varTestEndianness;

    printf("Hex: %x\n", (*(uint16_t *)pointer));

    varComposite.aVarArray[0] = 0;
    varComposite.aVarArray[1] = 126;
    printf("Hex: %x\n", varComposite.iVarInt);

    varTestEndianness.iVarInt = 1;

    if (varTestEndianness.aVarArray[0] == 1) {
        varComposite.aVarArray[0] = 126;
        varComposite.aVarArray[1] = 0;
    }
    else {
        varComposite.aVarArray[0] = 0;
        varComposite.aVarArray[1] = 126;
    }

    printf("Hex: %x\n", varComposite.iVarInt);

    return (0);
}


This is not portable as the underlying endianess of the system will affect result.

@Fredrik This addresses Lundin's "*(uint16_t*)pointer)  (i.e. pointer punning) may result undefined behavior" comment.

This didn't work. it outputs Hex: 7e00 Hex: 7e00

@ssd yes it solves the UB but still doesn't answer what OP wants to do.

@Ammar : Told you at the beginning of my post; "this is not an answer to your question." It's a more decent way of pointer punning.

Unions do solve UB concerns about alignment and strict aliasing, but they make the code endianness-dependent. Bit-shifts are generally better since they are not endianness-specific.

A weakness to (uint16_t *)pointer is that pointer may not have a value that meets the alignment needs of a uint16_t, leading to UB.  IOWs, uint8_t bytes[] lacks certain uint16_t alignment. "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Re “Told you at the beginning of my post; "this is not an answer to your question."”: Well, the thing is, posting answers is for posting text that answers the question. Saying your post is not an answer does not exempt it from the rules. If it is not a useful answer, it should not be posted as an answer and, once posted, it should be voted down or even deleted.

@EricPostpischil : haha. i won't delete it. having 200k+ karma, you'd better kick me out punk!
